# Wix Burn 3.6 RTM, still installing .NET 4.5 Beta

Tags: wix, bootstrapper

I'm using WiX [Burn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiX#Burn) to lay down .NET 4.5. It seems really straightforward from the documentation, *[How To: Install the .NET Framework Using Bur](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/install_dotnet.htm)*.

My installer is dead simple:

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
     xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension">
    <Bundle Name="My App"
            Version="1.0.0.0"
            Manufacturer="My Company"
            UpgradeCode="My GUID-4fa299bf4589"
            IconSourceFile="My Icon File" >
        <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense" >
            <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication
                SuppressOptionsUI="yes"
                LicenseFile="License.rtf"
                LogoFile="Installer_Banner.bmp"/>
        </BootstrapperApplicationRef>

        <Chain>
            <PackageGroupRef Id="NetFx45Web" />
            <MsiPackage
                DisplayName="My App Name"
                SourceFile="myMSI.msi"></MsiPackage>
        </Chain>
    </Bundle>
</Wix>
```

But when I run the generated EXE file it wants to install .NET 4.5 beta. I've got WiX 3.6.3303 which is RTM and [Visual Studio 2012](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2012) RTM. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: The source code **src\ext\NetFxExtension\wixlib\NetFx4.5.wxs** points to http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=223706 but it should point to http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=225704 [according to Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee942965.aspx#redist). Currently I see no way around this aside from re-compiling the source but I'm not an expert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct URLs for NETFX v4.5 are used in WiX v3.8. It was a mistake that the URLs were not updated sooner.